# WebGL OES_texture_float_linear android devices - Chrome

Tags: three.js, webgl, webgl-extensions

using threejs to create a sphere with texture. 
in Chrome (41.0.) on Samsung Tab 4 (Android 4.4.2) I am getting the following console:

`THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_float_linear extension not supported.`

causing my controls to stop working. 
sphere and texture are loaded.

any ideas?

------ UPDATE

threejs examples of DeviceControls not working on Samsung Tab4. Looks like more a device specific issue.

Comment: Patch Three.js so it uses half float? Check if the device has floating point support and if no then stop using the features of three.js that require floating point?

Comment: sounds good, got any documentation? thank you